# Solving transcendental equation and plotting solution

Tags: equation-solving, numerics, parametric-functions

I would like to solve

```
nf = 1.9;
ns = 1.89;
c = 3*^8;
H = 1.250*^-6;
B = Table[Sqrt[ (A/c)^2 nf^2 - (FindRoot[Tan[k*H/2]==Sqrt[(A/c)^2 (nf^2 -ns^2) - k^2]/k, {k,20}][[1, 2]])^2], {A, 0, 3*^15}]
ListPlot[B]
```

Am I missing something really obvious??

Comment: Do you also get a `SystemException["MemoryAllocationFailure"]`? My first step would be to look at the equation inside `FindRoot`. This function looks very weird and doesn't seem to have a root at all.

Comment: Note that `Table[..., {A, 0, 3*^15}]` implies evaluation of all values of $A$ between 0 and $3\times 10^{15}$ with a step of $1$. That seems unreasonable. If each evaluation took only 1 ms, the whole exercise would take on the order of 100,000 years, not to mention immense amounts of memory. Start by setting a reasonable step size, e.g. `{A, 0, 3*^15, 1*^14}`. You will at least get some results then.

Answer (score 1):

You have many many syntactic errors:

`c = 3*^8` makes no sense.  Presumably you mean `c = 3 10^8`

`H = 1.250*^-6` is wrong in several ways.  Presumably you mean `H = 1.250 10^(-6)`

You must assign `f`.

You should use a large step size (as @MarcoB writes).  And so on.

You should simplify by substituting values whenever possible.

You should avoid using upper-case letters to label a variable ALWAYS.

You need semicolon at the end of each functional line.

A start:

```
f = 7;
c = 3 10^8;
h = 1.250 10^(-6);
b = Table[
  Sqrt[(a/c)^2 1.9 f^2 - (FindRoot[
        Tan[k h/2] == Sqrt[(a/c)^2 (1.9^2 - 1.89^2) - k^2]/k, 
        {k, 20}][[1, 2]])^2], 
        {a, 0, 3 10^(15), 10^(14)}];
ListPlot[b]
```